# How to prove unimodality

Tags: real-analysis, convex-optimization, non-convex-optimization

I have a function $g(x)$ of $0\leq x \leq 1$, as the sum of the functions in the following forms

\begin{align}
f_1(x)&=(2-x)\frac{1-n}{m_1-n},\\
f_2(x)&=(2-x)x\frac{1-xn}{m_2-xn},\\ 
f_3(x)&=(2-x)(1-x)\frac{1-(1-x)n}{m_3-(1-x)n}
\end{align}

where $m_1,m_2,m_3,n$ have the same domain as $x$ with the constraints that all the denominators should be positive. So, it is clear that all the functions have positive value.

I want to find the minimum of $g(x)$. I want to prove that $g(x)$ is an increasing or decreasing or unimodal (or even bimodal with single minimum) function, so I can use some search algorithms. I can prove that $f_1(x)$ and $f_3(x)$ are decreasing functions and $f_2(x)$ is an increasing function, based on their derivatives. So $g(x)$ is the sum of increasing and decreasing functions of $x$. Is that enough to prove that $g(x)$ has a single minimum?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: No, consider the increasing and decreasing functions $2x+\sin(x)$ and $-2x+\sin(x)$.

Comment: If I am right, the numerator of the derivative is a quintic polynomial, and there is at least one real root, which should not be too difficult to find numerically. After deflation, you get a quartic, for which an analytic resolution is possible.

Comment: @Yves Daoust: good example, thanks. So in general, we can't prove. However, here, the stated functions have special forms and by plotting different cases, I have noticed that g(x) is either increasing or decreasing, or concave or convex; however I don't know how to prove analytically. About the numerator, in fact because g(x) is sum of two functions having the form of f1, one having the form of f2, and three having the form of f3, with different values of m1 and m3, the numerator has high degree. Anyway, what I am looking for is to prove at most two extremums.